# Flight Finder C++ unordered_map

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am having trouble finding adding a second vector on a flight.
For example when i reach sfo lax 89 in the data file lax 89 doesn't get added to sfo in the unordered_map.

Test data:

```
stl jfk 99
ord jfk 199
cle jfk 179
sfo jfk 388
sfo lax 89
stl cle 77
lax cle 30
sfo stl 200
ord stl 99
```

I tried to read through the input file finding all of the pairs the associated with a key and that didn't work either. I know this will work properly if i can get all my data into the unordered map. But i am really unsure on how to do that.

I am trying to get my stored data to look like this.

```
unordered_map<string, unordered_map<string, int>> vertices;

stl {jfk 99, cle 179}
ord {jfk 199, stl 99}
cle {jfk 179}
sfo {jfk 388, lax 89, stl 200}
lax {cle 30}
```

I was trying to use temp to store the second unordered_map in vertices by using temp.insert() to store the flights leaving from a given airport with the cost. Then using add_vertex() function i created.

I know the rest of the code works but i need to hard code the data in first to check it. But i need to be able to read that data from a file.

```
class Flight {

public:

unordered_map<string, unordered_map<string, int>> vertices;
int cost;

void add_vertex(string name, unordered_map<string, int>& edges){
    // Insert the connected nodes in unordered map
    vertices.insert(unordered_map<string, unordered_map<string, int>>::value_type(name, edges));
    }
};

void readData(ifstream &data2 , Flight &f, Flight &c) {
    while (true) {
        string
            departure,  // departure loc
            departureK,
            arrival,    // arrival loc
            arrivalk;
        string arrivals[250];
        int costs[250];
        int cost, costK;       // cost
        int size = 0;
        int pos;

        data2 >> departureK;
        if (data2.eof()) {
            return;
        }
        data2 >> arrivalk;
        data2 >> costK;

        pos = data2.tellg();
        unordered_map<string, int> temp;
        temp.insert(unordered_map<string, int>::value_type(arrivalk, costK));
        bool run = true;
        while (run) {
            data2 >> departure;
            if (data2.eof()) {
                run = false;
                return;
            }
            data2 >> arrival;
            data2 >> cost;
            if (departureK == departure) {
                arrivals[size] = arrival;
                costs[size] = cost;
                size++;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            temp.insert(unordered_map<string, int>::value_type(arrivals[i], costs[i]));
        }
        f.add_vertex(departureK, temp);
        c.add_vertex(departureK, temp);
        temp.clear();
        size = 0;
        data2.seekg(pos);

        /*data2 >> departure;
        if (data2.eof()) {
            return;
        }
        data2 >> arrival;
        data2 >> cost;
        unordered_map<string, int> temp;
        temp.insert(unordered_map<string, int>::value_type(arrival, cost));
        f.add_vertex(departure, temp);
        c.add_vertex(departure, temp);
        temp.clear();*/
    }
}

int main() {
    ifstream data2;

    char fileName[25];  // a string for filenames

    data2.clear();
    cout << "Please enter the name of the input file: ";
    cin >> fileName;

    data2.open(fileName, ios::in);
    if (!data2) {
        cerr << "Can't open input file " << fileName << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    // checks file
    Flight f, c;
    readData(data2, f, c);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You overcomplicate your code. If you read the specs for [`std::unordered_map::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at), you'll see that it adds a new value automagically when there isn't one yet:

> Reference to the mapped value of the new element if no element with key key existed. Otherwise a reference to the mapped value of the existing element whose key is equivalent to key.

So all you have to do is read the data from your file into `departure`, `arrival` and `cost`, and then do `vertices[departure][arrival] = cost;`.

If there is already an inner map for the departure, the new arrival is added to it. And if there isn't, a new map is created and then arrival is added to it.

Full example implementation of your `readData` method:

```
void readData(std::ifstream& data, Flight &f, Flight &c)
{
    std::string departure;
    std::string arrival;
    int cost;
    while (data >> departure >> arrival >> cost)
    {
        f.vertices[departure][arrival] = cost;
        c.vertices[departure][arrival] = cost;
    }
}
```

*(Please not that this code assumes the file is always valid and doesn't include any error handling.)*